# Creating an Interaction Test Class c# that takes in files from web.config

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, nunit, app-config

So I am trying to test a web service written in .NET framework 4.0 and c#. I am fairly new to the language and framework and language in general. My problem is that I want to create a test class for a service that takes an object from mongodb edits it then replaces it. I want to test the retrieval, editing, and saving of this object. The variables required for setting up server, db, and collection in the actual service are stored in web.config. I know I should use app.config for the test to load the relevant variables. My thought process for how to test this is to have two local mongodb databases: one that I load the objects off of and then persist them back and one that is clean for comparison st. Assert.NotEqual(changedDBObject, cleanDBObject) works.

Design wise is this a bad way of building this test? I could use some direction on the correct way to setup app.config preferably in a way that I can still use the same class that I use to read web.config. The main goal is to write a test class that does not require me to rework the original code beyond recognition just to use the test class and still be able to have a modular, reusable, fast running etc. test class.

Comment: Have you taken a look at unit tests? http://www.typemock.com/unit-testing-dot-net

Comment: The problem is the object itself is very large (>1000 lines as json) so doing anything other than pulling it off of the database is unreasonable and I also want to test pulling it off the database (in this case locally hosted) so unit testing is not enough